# What is the most efficient/common way to check if all parameters of a js function is non-empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, null

For example, I have a js function as follows:

```
function test(param1, param2, param3, ..., param10)
{
   //do something inside
}
```

What is the most efficient/common way to check if all the ten parameters are non-empty (empty here means NULL or an empty string. Note: 0 is not considered empty here!). Is the following method the best way?

```
function test(param1, param2, param3, ..., param10)
{
   if(param1==="" || param2==="" || ... || param10==="") )
   {
       //some parameters are empty string and should return false
   }
}
```

Please mark this one as duplicate if there is an exactly the same question. Thanks.

Comment: why not use an array as a param, then loop through the array to check if element is non empty

Comment: What is your definition of `empty`? Or do you mean you want to check that 10 arguments were given, irrelevant of their values?

Comment: @Xotic750, sorry for the unclearness. I have updated the question now. empty means NULL or empty string. Yes, I don't mind what the value is, as long as the value is given, even if it is given as 0.

Comment: Ok, so the number of arguments is irrelevant. Just each argument provided must be something other than `NULL` or `""`

Comment: that looks good!! I feel that would check even `undefined` type!

Comment: @Xotic750, I think so. I only need to check if all parameters are given a value. If not, return false; If yes, then proceed to the next steps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are asking. Uses [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which is ES5, but you could use a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop if you need to support older browsers.

```js
var pre = document.getElementById('out');
                                  
function log(str) {
    pre.textContent += str + '\n';
}

function argCheck(arg) {
    return arg !== null && arg !== '';
}

function test() {
    if (Array.prototype.every.call(arguments, argCheck)) {
        log('ok');
    } else {
        log('not ok');
    }
}

test();
test(0);
test('');
test(undefined);
test(null);
test(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
test(1, 2, 3, '', 5, 6);
test(1, 2, 3, null, 5, 6);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

If you need to check that a certain number of arguments is also provided then add a check

`arguments.length === X`

If you are wanting to check that the arguments evaluate to `true` then you could do

`Array.prototype.every.call(arguments, Boolean)`

Of course if you don't have many arguments to check, i.e. you only have one then the most (code)efficient way is to just test that 1 argument.

```
function test(arg1) {
    if (arg1 !== null && arg1 !== '') {
        log('ok');
    } else {
        log('not ok');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
function test(param1, param2)
{
   for (i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
       if (arguments[i] === ""){
        console.log("empty" + i);   
       }
}

test("not empty", "");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6tbnzjsu/

Here is another idea using the filter method:

```
function test(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    var notEmpty = [param1, param2, param3, param4];
    console.log(notEmpty);
    var filtered = notEmpty.filter(check);
    console.log(filtered);// Only first paramater will be returned "not empty", rest is filtered out
}

//filter function
function check(value) {
    return value !== "" && value !== null && value !== 0;

}

//call test function 
test("not empty", "", 0, null);
```

And the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/6tbnzjsu/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is this a more common practice than the method in my question?

Comment: The method in your question is checking if everything is evaluating to false, which is completely different than checking for empty strings or NULL.

Comment: I have updated the question. But to be concise, the parameters can either be an empty string or not in my case, so I don't pay much attention to the difference between being 0 or NULL or ''.

Comment: @Dainy I have updated my answer, maybe you are looking for a filter. I could not use the arguments array. I had to manually make a new array for the filter, probably because the arguments array is not a real array.

Comment: You can use `call` and pass `arguments` as the `this` value.

Comment: @Xotic750 Ok, thank! I did not know about the call method. I am programming in javascript abou a year now and I still learn new methods every day.

Comment: @Xotic750 What is the exact reason I can't use `arguments` as the array for the filter?

Comment: Because it is not an `array`, just an `array-like` object and so doesn't have the `array` methods in its `prototype`